# Why is there an error when I try to create a constructor for a class I have made?

Tags: vb.net

When I write the following code, the word 'New' is underlined, and an error message reads: 'Public Sub New.... should call InitializeComponent Method'.

```
Public Class Monster

Private poisonous
Private strength
Private monster_name

Public Sub New(givenPoisonous As Boolean, givenStrength As Integer, givenName As String)
    poisonous = givenPoisonous
    strength = givenStrength
    monster_name = givenName
End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: If this is a class for a form created from designer you have to call InitializeComponent() Method in the constructor body.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to add your own constructor to a form then you should start by writing one with no parameters. The IDE will add the call to `InitializeComponent` for you automatically. You can then add the parameters and you're good to go.  I just typed "public sub new" and then hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> and this is what I got:

```
Public Sub New()

    ' This call is required by the designer.
    InitializeComponent()

    ' Add any initialization after the InitializeComponent() call.

End Sub
```

Now that you have that constructor written though, you can just add a call to `InitializeComponent` at the top of it yourself.

```
Public Sub New(givenPoisonous As Boolean, givenStrength As Integer, givenName As String)
    InitializeComponent()

    poisonous = givenPoisonous
    strength = givenStrength
    monster_name = givenName
End Sub
```

That method contains most of the code generated by the designer.  It's where the controls and components that you added to the form in the designer get created, configured and added to the form.  If you want to see that code, click the 'Show All Files' button in the Solution Explorer, expand the node for your form and then open the designer code file.